# Suming elements from list in javascript

Tags: javascript

I've created a group of elements like this:

```
const teamRecords = [
  {
    team: 'A',
    results: [
      { season: '2007', game: 'G1', points: 3 }
      { season: '2007', game: 'g2', points: 3 }
      // ...
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to sum up all points from Season (2007 in this case). To to this, I try to use this function....Something is wrong with the function ...any idea what's the problem?

```
 var results;

 result.forEach(s => {
        result[s].forEach(Season=>{
            results[s].Points = [Season.map(Game => Points).reduce((a,b)=>a+b)]
        })
    })
```

At the end I would like to have this list:

```
const totaledResults = [
  {
    team: 'A',
    seasons: [{ season: '2007', points: '6' }]
  }
]
```

Comment: `result.forEach` - you have an object, not an array, so that won't work.

Comment: Are you sure about `Team : "A" : { ..}` and `Season : "2007" : [ ...`? This is a syntax error.

Comment: @SudheeshSinganamalla i changed the format

Comment: Something still is wrong. Are you still sure about `Team : "A" [...]`? Also is `Season` a key as `"Season":"2007"`?

Comment: 1) provide valid code 2) format that

Comment: @SudheeshSinganamalla I just removed "Season"... "A" is the key.

Comment: i think you should take a look at your code more seriously and carefully. In the latest update `"A" [ { Season : "2007" ....` doesn't still say "A" is a key. Did you mean: `"A" : [ { "Season" : "2007" ....` } ], `

Comment: @SudheeshSinganamalla yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to me if you want to find the value for only a single team and a single season or if you want to summarize everything.  If it's the latter, a function like this should do it:

```js
const seasonSummary = (teamRecords) => teamRecords.map(({team, results}) => {
  const games = results.reduce((all, curr) => {
    if (!(curr.season in all)) {all[curr.season] = 0;}
    all[curr.season] += curr.points
    return all
  }, {})
  return {team, results: Object.keys(games).map(season => ({season, points: games[season]}))}
})


const teamRecords = [{
  team: 'A',
  results: [
    { season: '2007', game: 'g1', points: 3 },
    { season: '2007', game: 'g2', points: 3 },
    { season: '2008', game: 'g1', points: 2 },
  ]
}, {
  team: 'B',
  results: [
    { season: '2007', game: 'g1', points: 1 },
    { season: '2008', game: 'g1', points: 5},
    { season: '2008', game: 'g2', points: 2},
  ]
}]

const summary = seasonSummary(teamRecords)

console.log(summary)
```

Note that `games` could be created simply using the `groupBy` function included in some of the libraries out there.  With [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#groupBy) (disclaimer: I'm a Ramda author) it would be

```
const games = R.groupBy(R.prop('season'), results)
```

With [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) or [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#groupBy) it would be something like

```
const games = _.groupBy(results, _.property('season'))
```

But if I were doing this in Ramda, I would probably have a different technique altogether:

```js
const {map, evolve, pipe, groupBy, prop, pluck, sum, toPairs, zipObj} = R;

const seasonSummary = map(evolve({
  results: pipe(
    groupBy(prop('season')),
    map(pluck('points')),
    map(sum),
    toPairs,
    map(zipObj(['season', 'points']))
  )
}))

const teamRecords = [{"results": [{"game": "g1", "points": 3, "season": "2007"}, {"game": "g2", "points": 3, "season": "2007"}, {"game": "g1", "points": 2, "season": "2008"}], "team": "A"}, {"results": [{"game": "g1", "points": 1, "season": "2007"}, {"game": "g1", "points": 5, "season": "2008"}, {"game": "g2", "points": 2, "season": "2008"}], "team": "B"}]

console.log(seasonSummary(teamRecords))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: What happens if I have only "A", "B" without team and results? Something like this [{'A':[ ] }]

Comment: That's an entirely different structure than your original.  I would suggest asking a new question if the data is different.

Comment: I changed the structure of the data and now it's ok. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!